# How to join a sum()'s result with a select query

Tags: mysql, sum

I've got a basic `transactions` table with 4 total columns as follows :

```
`transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fruit_id` int(11),
`person_id` int(11),
`quantity_bought` int(11),
```

example `select *` query :

| transaction_id | fruit_id | person_id | quantity_bought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | alex | 65 |
| 2 | banana | joe | 25 |
| 3 | banana | jenny | 70 |
| 4 | apple | dan | 80 |
| 4 | apple | danny | 50 |

i'm required to add the `total_quantity_bought` of each fruit to every row of this select query :

```
SELECT transactions.* FROM transactions;
```

here's an example of the desired output :

| transaction_id | fruit_id | person_id | quantity_bought | total_quantity_bought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | alex | 65 | 160 |
| 2 | banana | joe | 25 | 160 |
| 3 | banana | jenny | 70 | 160 |
| 4 | apple | dan | 80 | 130 |
| 4 | apple | danny | 50 | 130 |

this is what i tried so far and miserably failed :

```
select x.* , y.total_quantity_bought
from
   (SELECT *
    FROM transactions) x
    cross join
   (SELECT fruit_id , SUM(quantity_bought) AS total_quantity_bought
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY fruit_id) y
```

i thought of creating a `View` for sums like so, but i'm looking for a solution that doesnt require a `View`

| fruit_id | total_quantity_bought |
| --- | --- |
| banana | 160 |
| apple | 130 |

any help appreciated.

Comment: The best explained and formatted question I've seen... and from a new user.  Fantastic.

Comment: Thanks ! the account is actually ~5 years old , i just rarely ask question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically there.  Your `JOIN` wants to specify that for everything on the left (from the `transactions` table) should join to one associated total from the right (the `totals` subquery) ... and that join should be conditional on a matching `fruit_id`.

The performance of this query may drag (severely) as the dataset grows.  You might want to look at either caching the totals (using a database trigger etc) or rendering the totals in code elsewhere.

If you go for the latter (rendering it elsewhere), you might be interested in the `WITH ROLLUP` function:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-with-rollup/

```
SELECT
   transactions.*,
   totals.total_quantity_bought
FROM
   transactions   -- These are the individual transactions

   INNER JOIN     -- Join each individual transaction against the calculated totals

   (
    SELECT
       fruit_id,
       SUM(quantity_bought) AS total_quantity_bought
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY fruit_id
   ) as totals    -- These are the calculated totals (subqueried)

   ON totals.fruit_id = transactions.fruit_id
                  -- This joins the individual records to the totals by `fruit_id`
```

(Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74ae7e/10 )

Answer (score 1):

Possibly I just got beat to the answer, but here's my attempt

```
SELECT t.transaction_id, t.fruit_id, t.person_id, t.quantity_bought, grouped_fruit.total_quantity_bought
FROM transactions t
JOIN (
    SELECT fruit_id, SUM(quantity_bought) total_quantity_bought
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY fruit_id
) grouped_fruit ON t.fruit_id = grouped_fruit.fruit_id
```